# Unable to delete children in a bidirectional Many-to-one relationship

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mysql-workbench

TL;DR I am facing a tricky issue. I can see the delete sql queries being logged in the application logs, but when I run a select sql query for the deleted rows, I can still see the data.

---

I have a bidirectional Many-To-One Mapping. I am trying to delete the children so that I can save brand new children.

- @Query delete query
- orphanRemoval
- To make sure there are no references to children in the parent when the delete query is run, removed children from the parent, saved the parent with empty children list, then called the jpa repository deleteAll method to delete the children from child table.

I have logged both hibernate queries and jdbc queries, I can clearly see that the delete queries are being issued. But the deleted rows still show up in the workbench.

Edit

As the image below shows, the query does reach mysql. I have enabled `general_log` and the image shows what is being logged. The records are all still there even though mysql seems to have executed the delete query This is the state immediately after the line of code which executes delete query. So there is no other code reinserting the records in the database. I am clearly missing something. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If you are removing the children from the parent, and have orphan removal set on the collection - why do you need to manually remove the children? JPA, if you are doing this in a transaction (and you should), will clear them for you. If that isn't happening, it might that you have some other instance of this parent entity re-inserting them.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. Transactions weren't setup properly. I realized this when I looked at `SET autocommit=0` but no corresponding `SET autocommit=1` in the mysql general log. So, even though the queries were reaching mysql, they weren't being committed. I went back and re-did transactions and the delete started working as expected. 

I found the problem yesterday during day time (IST). I haven't had time to post it here as I am in the process of looking at 1.5 years of my code and 3+ years of others' code to see if the issue exists elsewhere.